# Mock keyboard event and test stopImmediatePropagation is called with React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a functional component that has a `handleKeyDown` function:

```
const handleKeyDown = () => {
   if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
       e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()
   }
}

return (
  <input onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} //etc />
)
```

How do I test that BACKSPACE, the `e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation` gets called?

I'm using enzyme/react-testing library and jest.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `enzyme`, you can simulate the keydown event by using [.simulate(event[, ...args])](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html#simulateevent-args--self) on the shallow wrapper. Create a mocked keydown event object and pass it to the `.simulate()` method.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export function App() {
  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
      e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
  };

  return <input onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} />;
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { App } from './';

describe('68566755', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    const mEvent = {
      key: 'Backspace',
      nativeEvent: { stopImmediatePropagation: jest.fn() },
    };
    wrapper.simulate('keydown', mEvent);
    expect(mEvent.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68566755/index.test.tsx (8.625 s)
  68566755
    ✓ should pass (5 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 5                 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.174 s, estimated 10 s
```